# Populate MatBlazor MatAutocompleteList with values from an object list

Tags: blazor-client-side, matblazor

I am working on an application using .Net Core 3.1 and client side Blazor. I am using [MatBlazor](https://www.matblazor.com/AutocompleteList) components but I am unable to get the MatAutocompleteList to load. The data is retrieved from an API and converted to an object list when the page loads:

```
    List<CountryDto> countries = new List<CountryDto>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await ReadCountries();
    }

    ...

    async Task ReadCountries()
    {
        ApiResponseDto apiResponse = await Http.GetJsonAsync<ApiResponseDto>( "api/country" );

        if ( apiResponse.StatusCode == 200 )
        {
            countries = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CountryDto []>( apiResponse.Result.ToString() ).ToList<CountryDto>();
        }
    }
```

Then I am referencing the data in the autocomplete list like this (similar to the [example](https://www.matblazor.com/AutocompleteList)):

```
<MatAutocompleteList @bind-Value="@church.Country" Items="@countries" Label="Select Country" TItem="CountryDto" CustomStringSelector="@(i => i.Name)" />
```

No matter how I configure the autocomplete box, the page fails to load and Chrome Dev tools shows a string of unhandled errors rendering the component.

[image]

I have tried configuring it different ways using the examples but I always get the same errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.  A workaround was explained [here](https://github.com/SamProf/MatBlazor/issues/213). A new version of the control is in the works so hopefully this new component will solve the issue.